# Query não retorna resultados no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Existe uma query no meu PHP onde busca a lista de email e retorna para o PHP, porém, não está me retornando nenhum resultado.

O Code PHP está assim:

```
      <?php
      session_start("admin");
      if($_SESSION["admin"] == "on"){
      include("../config.php");
      ?>
      <?php
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `n_emails` WHERE 1");
      $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      while($lista2=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
      $email = $lista2["email"];
      $ativo = $lista2["ativo"];
      if($ativo=="n"){
      $ativo = "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='red'>Não confirmado</font>";
      }
      else{
      $ativo = "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='green'>Confirmado</font>";
      }
      ?>
      <tr>
      <td width="50%">
      <p align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="2"><?=$email?></font>          </b></td>
      <td width="25%"><?=$ativo?></td>
      <td width="25%"><a href="javascript:remove('<?=$email?>')">
      <font face="Arial" size="2">remover</font></a></td>
      </tr><?php } ?>
      <?php
      }
      else{
      echo "<script>location.href='login.php'</script>";
      }
      ?>
```

Quando eu rodo esta query  manualmente, me retorna os resultados todos corretos. Não entendo o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Coloque o código mais completo. O problema não está na query.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Basicamente é isso

Comment: Você está selecionando errado.  Apaga esse WHERE 1.

Comment: resolvido, só trocar a query, obrigado Denis e Filipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução para o problema, troquei a query:

```
  SELECT `email` FROM `n_emails` WHERE 1
```

por essa:

```
  SELECT * FROM n_emails order by -id
```

E funcionou.